# How to change how often Outlook checks messages?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

Where can I find settings which can change how often Outlook will check for new emails?

Comment: Outlook or Outlook Express? Which version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Outlook 2010, follow these instructions:
[image]

There'll be not much difference between this and any other version of outlook.

Answer (score -1):

The new Outlook 2017 doesn't have a feature to set this up. I have to keep Outlook closed and manually open it every 3 hours.

Comment: Consider adding some reference supporting what you state after confirming it's relevant to this question at the time it was asked, etc.